# ios - How can I dismiss(close) the load UIViewController on the window

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, popup, containers, dismiss

I have a question, I want to build popup view like the `UIAlertView`,

I create two `UIViewController` in the storyboard(note: there are not segue),and Root `UIViewController` will load the `UIViewController` view popup.

I create two `UIViewController` to edit the `UIView`, because I want to use the storybaord to edit my complex `UIView` in the feature.

Then I put the container view on the `RootViewController` and there are two button in the container view.(my structure as below:)

[image]

When I click the pop up green button(with button name `popupGreenBtn`), It can correct `addSubview` on  the `UIWindow`.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
     NSLog(@"ContainerViewController view didload");

 appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

 secondGreenVC = (SecondGreenViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondGreenViewController"];

 thirdRedVC = (ThirdRedViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdRedViewController"];

 }

 - (IBAction)popupGreenBtnAction:(id)sender {

     [appDelegate.window addSubview: secondGreenVC.view];
     [appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:secondGreenVC.view];

 }

 - (IBAction)popupRedBtnAction:(id)sender {
     [appDelegate.window addSubview: thirdRedVC.view];
     [appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:thirdRedVC.view];

 }
```

When I click the button , it can correct popup on the window:

[image] [image]

But now , When I  click the `SecondGreenViewController` and `ThirdRedViewcontroller` background view(just transparent dark black), I want to close the popon the view(`secondGreenVC.view` or `thirdRedVC.view`).

I had try to add the code in the `SecondGreenViewController` class below:

```
 @implementation SecondGreenViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
     [_secondBaseView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
 }

 -(void) tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
 {
     [self removeFromParentViewController];
      //    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
     NSLog(@"tap in SecondGreenViewController");
 }
 @end
```

There are not effect to close the `UIViewController`.

**How can I close the Popup window(the `UIViewController`) when I click the dark black part?**

(If you want to more info, please tell me or you can see my this  simple project from github https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/PopUpViewDemo )

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(void) tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
thirdViewcontroller.hidden=YES;
 }
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers, add some explaination.

Comment: you can dissmiss the thirdViewController if it is Presented over your secondViewcontroller.. here you added your thirdViewcontroller as a subview of secondViewcontroller...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem. But I don't know have any best answer.

My method is in the popupGreenBtnAction actin.

change the code to:

```
  appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
  secondGreenVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
  [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:secondGreenVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then in the SecondGreenViewController storyboard,

Drag an other UIView do base UIView and set the UIView IBOutlet(now I name with"secondBaseView").

at SecondGreenViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
     [self.secondBaseView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
 }

 -(void) tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
 {
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
 }
```

That is Ok to show the modal and dismiss the modal UIViewController.